# fopen won't open file on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

The following function is normally able to open a file on xampp with no problems

```
/* converts string to xml*/
public function stringToXMLFile($string){
    $file = __DIR__."/xml/feed.xml";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w+') or die("can't open file: ".$file);
    fwrite($fh, $string);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

But since uploading all my files onto an Ubuntu server I can not get fopen() to open and edit any files, is there something that I have to do on a newly installed Ubuntu Apache server  which will give permission to perform such tasks?

Comment: An error message you're getting would be really helpful here to help you debug the problem.

Comment: what are the permissions on the files / run the program using sudo?

Comment: Apache2 is probably running as the "www-data" user. You need to check that the directory where the PHP file is located and therefore where you try to write the file allows this user to write in it.

Comment: @SirDarius the files are under var/www

Comment: @mk_89 - that is a sensible location to place php files, however, what are the current permissions for this directory ?

Comment: @SirDarius Sorry im new to this, I just configured the server today, how do you check permissions? I'll also try to google it myself

Comment: @SirDarius I tried `ls -ld /var/www/` and the following was returned `drwxrwxr-x 9 root www-data 4096 Sep  5 23:26 /var/www/`

Comment: the owner of the directory is root, and the group is www-data. The output means that root can read/write/traverse the directory, as well as members of the www-data group. Therefore, if apache is executed with an effective user group www-data, it should be able to write in /var/www. Note that this is not necessarily true for sub-directories.

Comment: @SirDarius so your saying I should be able to write to the root, but possibly not to var/www

Comment: @mk_89: Can you show output of `ls -ld /var/www/xml` please?

Comment: @favoretti `drwxr-xr-x 6 root www-data 4096 Sep  5 23:32 /var/www/xml`

Comment: There you go, change that dir permissions to `775` and it should work. End result should look like `drwxrwxr-x`.

Comment: @favoretti would the command `/var/www premissions set to 775` change the permission?

Comment: Nope, `chmod 775 /var/www/xml` would do the trick.

Comment: @favoretti Ok, I have changed it and I get `drwxrwxr-x` but it still doesn't allow me to open the file

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16334/discussion-between-favoretti-and-mk-89)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having discussion in the chat, the problems were:

1. Permissions on `/var/www/xml` directory.
2. Permissions on `/var/www/xml/feed.xml` file.

After adjusting them to proper values, problem was solved.